# shifted convolutions as a replacements to masked convolutions in pixelcnn++

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I read the PixelCnn++ [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05517.pdf) and [code](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn/blob/bbc15688dd37934a12c2759cf2b34975e15901d9/pixel_cnn_pp/nn.py).

in the code, there is this line (298):

```
''' utilities for shifting the image around, efficient alternative to masking convolutions '''
```

aftwerwards, they define several functions for that purpuse:
down_shifted_conv2d, down_right_shifted_conv2d, down_shift, right_shift.

using these and gated_resnet layers, they (based on figure 2 from the paper) convert the image from 32X32 to 8X8, and back to 32X32.  I looked into these layers - it seems like down_shift adds a bottom row of zeros, and down_shifted_conv2d adds some specific padding and using a specific kernel size.

also, they divide the [model](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn/blob/bbc15688dd37934a12c2759cf2b34975e15901d9/pixel_cnn_pp/model.py) to up u_list (line 37) and ul_list (38), which I think might correspond to downwards and downward+rightward streams mentioned briefly in the paper after figure 2.

lastly, in the beginning of the model, they pad the last axis with 1 (line 37), and state that it is for:

```
 add channel of ones to distinguish image from padding later on
```

my questions are:

1. how are the shifted convolutions a replacement for masked convolutions - that is, how they prevent the network for seeing future pixel value through the layers? and why are they called "shifted"?
2. what is the downwards and downward_rightwards streams, how do they work and are they the same as the u_list and ul_list?
3. why they pad the last axis of the input with ones, in what way it helps them later?